# How to make the whole page scrollable that contains a GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Page that contains a navigationDrawer, imageView, two flipperView and a gridView. Earlier only the gridView was scrollable so to make the whole page scrollable I put all the views in a nestedScrollView but now even the gridView is unscrollable. And also the first flipperView doesn't show any flippers, just the plain blue background view is displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehaviour">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehaviour"
        android:alpha="0.4"/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0F0F0F"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxxx.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#ff77"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/banner1"
            android:src="@drawable/b1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#2252FF"
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/flipper1">
        </technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#2252FF">
        <technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Flipper2">
        </technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#fff090"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0f0f0f"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp">
        </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: okay my bad , will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

ListViews have its own scrollable behaviour. You need to cancel to add this to the GridView and maybe to de FliperLayouts as well.

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Or by code:

```
gridView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: still the whole page is unscrollable